# What will be the passive voice sentences for these sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, passive-voice, speech, active-voice

1. How many men are there?
2. How much milk he buys?
3. There are books.
4. It is a toy.
5. Books are there.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no passive when you use 'be' as a main verb because after 'be' we use a complement but it is an object that is required when you create the passive voice.  For 2 maybe: How much milk are bought by him?